# Location returning null sometime after Location Service is turned on Android

Tags: android, android-fusedlocation

I am trying to get `Latitude` and `Longitude` from the device using `FusedLocationApi` . If the location is turned off I am asking the user to turn on the location service through a `dialog`. Once the location service is turned on sometime I am getting the `Longitude` and `Latitude` . But sometime its returning `Location` as null. Here is the code to get the `Latitude` and `Longitude` using the `FusedLocationApi`. **Problem comes when the user has to turn on the Location Service using the dialog**

```
private void getLatLong() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                // The next two lines tell the new client that “this” current class will handle connection stuff
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                //fourth line adds the LocationServices API endpoint from GooglePlayServices
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        //Disconnect from API onPause()
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //Now lets connect to the API
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Log.e("GoogleApiClient", "Connected");
            settingsRequest();
        }
    }

    private void settingsRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient

        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                Log.e("StatusCode", status.getStatusCode() + "");
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        Log.e("GoogleAfterLocation", mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() + "");
                        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {

                            // check if the device has OS Marshmellow or greater than
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
                                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(RegistrationActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(RegistrationActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(RegistrationActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_CODE);
                                } else {
                                    // get Location
                                    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

                                    Log.e("Location", location + "");
                                    if (location == null) {
                                        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, RegistrationActivity.this);

                                        Alerter.create(RegistrationActivity.this)
                                                .setTitle(R.string.warning)
                                                .setDuration(2000)
                                                .setBackgroundColor(R.color.dot_dark_screen1)
                                                .setText("Please turn on the Location from settings and start the application")
                                                .show();

                                    } else {
                                        //If everything went fine lets get latitude and longitude
                                        currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                                        currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                                        if (currentLatitude != -0.0 && currentLongitude != -0.0) {
                                            //Get Weather Data
                                            //getWeatherData(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
                                            Log.e("PermissionGranted", currentLatitude + " " + currentLongitude);
                                        } else {
                                            Alerter.create(RegistrationActivity.this)
                                                    .setTitle(R.string.warning)
                                                    .setText("Please Check internet connectivity")
                                                    .setDuration(1500)
                                                    .setBackgroundColor(R.color.dot_dark_screen1)
                                                    .show();
                                        }
                                        // Toast.makeText(this, currentLatitude + " WORKS " + currentLongitude + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                // get Location
                                Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

                                if (location == null) {
                                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, RegistrationActivity.this);

                                } else {
                                    //If everything went fine lets get latitude and longitude
                                    currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                                    currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                                    if (currentLatitude != -0.0 && currentLongitude != -0.0) {
                                        //Get Weather Data
                                        //getWeatherData(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
                                        Log.e("Lollipop", currentLatitude + " " + currentLongitude);
                                    } else {
                                        Alerter.create(RegistrationActivity.this)
                                                .setTitle(R.string.warning)
                                                .setText("Please Check internet connectivity")
                                                .setDuration(1500)
                                                .setBackgroundColor(R.color.dot_dark_screen1)
                                                .show();

                                    }
                                    // Toast.makeText(this, currentLatitude + " WORKS " + currentLongitude + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(RegistrationActivity.this, REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // This method is called only on devices having installed Android version >= M (Marshmellow)
    // This method is just to show the user options for allow or deny location services at runtime
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 3310: {

                if (grantResults.length > 0) {

                    for (int i = 0, len = permissions.length; i < len; i++) {

                        if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                            // Show the user a dialog why you need location
                        } else if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            // get Location
                            getLatLong();
                        } else {
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.e("RequestCode", requestCode + "");
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR) {
            mResolvingError = false;
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Log.e("LocationDialog", "Turned On");
                    // get location method
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(RegistrationActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(RegistrationActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                        //                                          int[] grantResults)
                        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                        return;
                    }
                    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

                    if (location == null) {
                        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, RegistrationActivity.this);

                    } else {
                        //If everything went fine lets get latitude and longitude
                        currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                        currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                        if (currentLatitude != -0.0 && currentLongitude != -0.0) {
                            //Get Weather Data
                            //getWeatherData(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
                        } else {

                            Alerter.create(RegistrationActivity.this)
                                    .setTitle(R.string.warning)
                                    .setText("Please Check internet connectivity")
                                    .setDuration(1500)
                                    .setBackgroundColor(R.color.dot_dark_screen1)
                                    .show();

                        }

                        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), currentLatitude + " WORKS " + currentLongitude + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    finish();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        /*
             * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
             * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
             * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
             * error.
             */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mResolvingError = true;
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(RegistrationActivity.this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                    /*
                     * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                     * PendingIntent
                     */
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        } else {
                /*
                 * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
                 * user with the error.
                 */
            showErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode());
            mResolvingError = true;
            Log.e("Error", "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    /* Creates a dialog for an error message */
    private void showErrorDialog(int errorCode) {
        // Create a fragment for the error dialog
        ErrorDialogFragment dialogFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
        // Pass the error that should be displayed
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DIALOG_ERROR, errorCode);
        dialogFragment.setArguments(args);
        dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "errordialog");
    }

    /* Called from ErrorDialogFragment when the dialog is dismissed. */
    public static void onDialogDismissed() {
        mResolvingError = false;
    }


    /* A fragment to display an error dialog */
    public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        public ErrorDialogFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Get the error code and retrieve the appropriate dialog
            int errorCode = this.getArguments().getInt(DIALOG_ERROR);
            return GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(
                    this.getActivity(), errorCode, REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            onDialogDismissed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
```

This line is returning null after the location is turned on:

```
Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Yeah I got the solution @Leone